# Accidentally deleted friends Apple ID

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I bought my friend's iPhone from her. I reset the iPhone and accidentally lost her Apple ID and everything that was purchased and backed up to iCloud.

She gave me her username and password but when I try to log in using a browser it says "no Apple ID found". Please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you asking about how to remove the device from iCloud following this method - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201351 ? Your post is confusing since it is **impossible** to delete an Apple ID. What is easy is removing the data on a device that came from the cloud thereby removing that ID from that device, but you **cannot** delete the ID itself.

Comment: Which website are you trying to log in?

Comment: Try her to search in her mail archive for traces of Apple emails.  That's probably the only chance of recovering it.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot delete an Apple ID by just resetting a device.  Doing an actual delete can be done other ways but it requires multiple actions; calling the Apple support desk and clicking a confirmation link sent via email being two of them.

If you cannot login into icloud.com or id.apple.com with the given credentials means those credentials you got from your friend are incorrect.

*** UPDATE appearantly deleting is only possible in selected countries.

Comment: You ***cannot*** by any method, actually delete an Apple ID. It is simply not possible.

Comment: @Tetsujin Apple can delete the ID if you call them and insist on it. It is actually required to be an option under the law of several European countries.

Comment: That would require real effort, & a phone call - by the ID's owner. For the purposes of this QA, not a valid argument.

Comment: Ah right, sorry to submit an invalid argument ;) On your comment I read the emphasis on "cannot" rather than on "you".